# Created new torrent but client unable to find seeds

Tags: bittorrent

I tried creating a new torrent, using uTorrent, following the directions from [torrentfreak](http://torrentfreak.com/how-to-create-a-torrent/).  I used a bunch of trackers (just in case any individual one was having troubles) and uTorrent shows it as "seeding" with 100% of the file.  It shows: seeds 0(1), peers 0(0).

```
http://exodus.desync.com/announce
http://eztv.tracker.prq.to/announce
http://open.tracker.thepiratebay.org/announce
http://www.torrent-downloads.to:2710/announce
http://denis.stalker.h3q.com:6969/announce
udp://denis.stalker.h3q.com:6969/announce
http://www.sumotracker.com/announce
```

I've also attempted to remove the torrent and then re-add the torrent, pointing it to my already existing files, forcing uTorrent to recheck the files and then begin seeding.

Yet when I share the .torrent file with my other computer and attempt to download, it is unable to find any peers or seeds.

To confirm that both clients are working, I downloaded a torrent on both computers, using their respective clients, using torrents I found on isohunt.  This tells me that there must be something wrong in how I'm creating my torrents.

Comment: Does it not find any seeds or can it not connect to the seeds? Can you clarify this? Also - I had my share of problems with BitTorrent too, with it not finding seeds which are practically there (online it says there are xxx seeds, and most my client doesn't even see) and I could never resolve them#

Answer (score 1):

When you create a torrent, you are the only seed until some peers start downloading your file, once they have a full copy they will be added to the number of seeds available.

Did you open/check the ports forwarded on your router to accommodate your torrent clients?

Your clients should be configured to use a port of your choice in this range= 49160–65534