# The torrent is seeding in my torrent client but others can't download the files, how to seed correctly?

Tags: bittorrent

I created a torrent by following the approach mentioned in this [link](https://torrentfreak.com/how-to-create-a-torrent/).

The torrent status is showing as seeding on my machine. I kept on a VirtualBox VM< with NAT connection.

But, it is not downloading when I try to test on an another machine, which is on a different network.

Found a similar question [here on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/240271/created-new-torrent-but-client-unable-to-find-seeds), but no answers there.