# Why won't my torrent client download a test torrent I created?

Tags: networking, router, bittorrent

I found [two](https://superuser.com/questions/1595433/the-torrent-is-seeding-in-my-torrent-client-but-others-cant-download-the-files) [posts](https://superuser.com/questions/240271/created-new-torrent-but-client-unable-to-find-seeds) that are similar to mine, but they do not have a solution to the issue I'm seeing.

I created a test torrent using `mktorrent` and added some open trackers to it. I am seeding this torrent using `HostA`, which is using `qBittorrent` 4.3.7. It is on port `32123`, which is forwarded correctly in my router for both TCP and UDP.

I then tried to download the torrent using `aria2c` 1.35.0 on `HostB`. This is the output:

```
ubuntu@HostA:~$ aria2c testtorrent.torrent --console-log-level=debug | grep '32123'
09/21 13:00:34 [DEBUG] Checkout peer HostA:32123 to CUID#48
09/21 13:00:35 [INFO] CUID#48 - Connecting to HostA:32123
09/21 13:00:35 [DEBUG] CUID#48 - Peer HostA:32123 banned.
09/21 13:00:36 [INFO] CUID#48 - Connecting to HostA:32123
09/21 13:00:36 [INFO] CUID#48 - To: HostA:32123 handshake peerId=A2-1-35-0-%00%A8%21n2%2C%E8%CD%B8%EC, reserved=0000000000100005
Exception: [PeerConnection.cc:215] errorCode=1 Got EOF from peer.
09/21 13:00:36 [DEBUG] CUID#48 - Peer HostA:32123 banned.
09/21 13:00:36 [DEBUG] Peer HostA:32123 returned from CUID#48
```

Here is a packet capture between the two hosts (`192.168.1.66` is HostA)

[Packet Capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AFzVy.png)

I would think my ISP might be interfering, but the `[FIN, ACK]` comes from `HostA`.

Comment: If you are behind a isp firewall (private ip), then this is your issue, you need a public ip from your isp.

Comment: I have a dedicated public IP from my ISP. That's the announce IP and the IP I see in my logs. Other services such as HTTP/S work fine in the same configuration.

Answer (score 0):

After extensive testing*, I was able to fix this issue by enabling "**Allow multiple connections from the same IP address**" in qBittorrent.  You can see evidence of multiple connections in the Wireshark screenshot, where HostB sends two packets before HostA can respond.

* This included making my own tracker, connecting over LAN, using a VPN, using a cloud load balancer, and more.

Comment: I'm having exactly the same problem but I use Transmission. I also tried Deluge, rtorrent and transmission-daemon. All of those do not have a setting like that. I wonder what it actually does behind the curtain.

Comment: "Allow multiple connections from the same IP address — (default: disabled) Determines if connections from the same IP address as existing connections should be rejected or not. This option is disabled by default to prevent abusive behavior by peers. It may be useful to allow such connections in cases where simulations are run on the same machine, and all peers in a swarm have the same IP address." https://github.com/qbittorrent/qBittorrent/wiki/Explanation-of-Options-in-qBittorrent#libtorrentspecific_configuration